# MySQL refuses to return 24hr time - all times in modified 12hr

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

Our production MySQL server refuses to return times in 24hr format, opting for 12hr instead. I searched SO and Google but all questions refer to formatting and I have no problems formatting.

A basic example;

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399);
+---------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399) |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-09-23 05:49:59       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Checking http://www.epochconverter.com/

> Your time zone: 9/23/2015, 3:49:59 PM GMT+10:00

Its not a time issue, it is actually 15:49 pm.

The thing is, even if I try to force a 24hr format it still wont do it ...

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399), "%T"));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399), "%T")) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  5 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The interesting thing is that in 12hr it'd be 3, not 5. In 24hr it'd be 15. So, its not correct by either format.

Curiously, we're in a +10 timezone, could it be deducting 10hrs for some reason?

It doesn't matter what time the timestamp is... I've tested this across many, many timestamps and rows in the db.

All these queries work as expected on my local and dev servers. I'm not new to MySQL date functions. I am new to this problem though.

**On my local;**

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399), "%T"));
+----------------------------------------------------+
| HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399), "%T")) |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 15 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Well aware that I can drop the DATE_FORMAT also, its only there for a fair comparison.

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399));
+---------------------------------+
| HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399)) |
+---------------------------------+
|                              15 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @irina-avram it was a time_zone problem.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%time_zone%';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| system_time_zone | UTC   |
| time_zone        | UTC   |
+------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acording to this, the value is given in the current timezone, the one of your provider:

> FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format):
>
> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on
>   whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value
>   is expressed in the current time zone. unix_timestamp is an internal
>   timestamp value such as is produced by the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function.

( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime )

But you could try this:

```
SET time_zone='+10:00';
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1442987399);
```

Comment: As updated in my question, I can see that the time_zone is set to UTC.

Comment: well, that explains it :)